# Does Lord Krishna indirectly say that Sudras are Dogs or its a misunderstanding of commentators?

Tags: krishna, bhagavata-purana

A brāhmaṇa cannot in any circumstances become like a dog, accepting an ordinary master.(ŚB 11.17.47). Srila Prabhupada writes "Śva-vṛttyā, or “a dog’s profession,” refers to the śūdras, who cannot live without accepting a master"

Also in next verse, its said "A king  can never follow the course of an obedient dog" (SB 11.17.48)

Edit : In Motilal translation for the same verse, its said " A Brahmana should never resort to Dog's way of life by undertaking lower jobs. "

So does Lord indirectly say Sudras are Dogs ?

Comment: Shudras are the servant varna, and dogs are servants too, so both share the quality of servitute. That's all it's saying. It's not saying that "shudras are dogs" like some insult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wanted to add my opinion as an answer. In regards to context, Krishna might have said so to stop Bramhanas and Ksatriyas from doing Materialistic Jobs, for their duties and responsibilities towards society are much higher. It doesn't use that harsh language on Vaishyas. As regards respect is considered, we can look at Vedas -

> Salutations and salutations, To him who is the potter, And to him who
> is the black smith. Salutations and salutations, To him who is the
> hunter of birds who uses nets, And to him who is the fisherman.
> Salutations and salutations, To him who hunts animals, And to him who
> drags dogs using a rope. Salutations and salutations, To him who is a
> dog, And to him who protects the dogs. (Rudram Chamakam 4.2.5-9)
>
> O God grant love to our holy priests, set love in our ruling chiefs.
> Grant love to the Vaishyas and Shudras; give out of Thy unbounded
> store of love, love unto me!(Yajur Veda 18.48)
>
> May all beings look upon me with the eye of a friend. May I see all
> beings through the eye of friendship - may we all look upon each other
> as friends. (Yajur Veda 36.18)

As regards Bhagavata also we can see another statement which asks us to understand that Brahman alone is pervading in all beings-

> One should give up the bodily conception and should offer obeisances
> before all- even the dogs,cows and asses falling flat upon the ground
> like a rod. Until one has fully developed the ability to see Me within
> all living beings, one must continue to worship Me by this process
> with the activities of his speech, mind and body.(Srimad Bhagavatam
> 11.29.17)